# Updating gcache.size on a Three Node Cluster

Tags: percona, galera

Is it possible to update this value on Percona 5.7 without restarting a node?

Also, do I need to bring the entire cluster down to update the setting, or can I update one node at a time?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Galera Documentation on [wsrep Options](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/mysql-wsrep-options.html) and [Galera Parameters](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/galera-parameters.html#gcache-size), gcache is not Dynamic.

> Is it possible to update this value on Percona 5.7 without restarting a node?

Answer is no. I am sorry

> Also, do I need to bring the entire cluster down to update the setting, or can I update one node at a time?

Not sure, but I would bring down the whole cluster just to be thorough. Since the cache is not dynamic for an individual node, you would not want any weird behavior have nodes with and without caches size the same size and the same way in a given cluster.

Comment: Could you do a rolling update of the cash by taking down one node at a time and adding value to them? I mostly cannot afford any down time.

Comment: Since the gcache is a local file, I would say go for it. I would test it out on a staging server first